# Alternating row color in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following HTML:

```
<table id="ChatTable" class="ChatBox" style="margin-left:0px !important">
            <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="PopupInnerContent">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Are you guys open today? What is your return policy?</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <table class="PopupInnerContent">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hi yes we are open today. Out return policy is 7 days with original receipt.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea class="mediumResolution required"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I have applied 
following JQuery :

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".ChatBox tr:even").css("background-color", "#EAEAEA");
            $(".ChatBox tr:odd").css("background-color", "Blue");
        });
    </script>
```

Problem is that after applying above Jquery. tr containing innerTable also get affected by this Jquery: How can i prevent to affect color in InnerTable's Tr ??

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".ChatBox > tr:pseudoclass")
```

USE > IN BETWEEN FOR ACCESS TO CHILDREN

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ChatBox > tr:even").css("background-color", "#EAEAEA");
        $(".ChatBox > tr:odd").css("background-color", "Blue");
    });
</script>
```

to apply only to direct children of `.chatbox`

Comment: Are you sure that inner tables don't have a background set? Can you check in firebug if the styles are set properly?

Comment: yes even i remove class name for innerTable and applied > in Jquery, it Removes all background color from the table

Comment: First of all, you should check if the jquery script is executing correctly. If it sets the `background-color` on `tr` as expected, then the problem is somewhere else, probably in the CSS. If it doesn't set the `background-color` properly, then we need to debug the javascript.

Comment: ya its working properly in my case(without adding '>' ) after adding > it losts whole effect.

Comment: Then it is a problem in your CSS files. When the javascript was applying to style to the inner tr tables, was overwriting the existing background rules. Check this out http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ to see how the direct selector works

Answer (score 0):

Try out this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ChatBox > tbody > tr:odd').css("background-color", "Blue");
    $('.ChatBox > tbody > tr:even').css("background-color", "#EAEAEA");

});
```